# Laravel Socialite Call to undefined method Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\User::get()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel socialite to get user info from access token. It work fine at local (using vagrant). But not working in server AWS.

And got message

> "message": "Call to undefined method
>   Laravel\Socialite\Two\User::get()",

My code is here

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
...
$socialUser =  Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($accessToken);
```

Comment: the composer is updated on the server? this is due to file missing upload files from your local otherwise with ssh update composer

Comment: Maybe you have different versions, and the one in AWS hasn't got that method?

Comment: Yeah. I tried composer update 2 time. Also remove vendor folder and run composer update

Comment: @Amarnasan Both of local and server using php 7.1

Comment: I mean the Socialite version, not the php version

Comment: composer dump-autoload use this command on server to load files for access

Comment: @Amarnasan ya local and server has same version laravel socialite

Comment: @sunil sad :( . Still not working

Comment: userfromToken have u updated database this is due to also of not found relationship on server

Comment: if you local system is on windows then try to check file name first letter must be in capital letter for amazon (ubuntu server)

Comment: @sunil yeah. My Controller file already capital `SocialAuthController.php`

Comment: Is $accessToken looking ok? dump and check it...

Comment: @CalinBlaga yeah token is good. It working fine at local. But wrong in aws.

Comment: Update. I chang to do it without using laravel socialite, and work fine now. Thank for helping me. Guys